# Invalid syntax Python, pylint (syntax-error)

Tags: python

Mi gente estoy repasando un poco de Python, y estaba con algo básico, pero me tiro este error, no se si soy yo, pero no encuentro el problema. Agradecería mucho la ayuda. Les dejo el codigo:

```
nombre = (input("Ingresa tu nombre: ")

ed = int(input("Ingresa tu edad: "))

print("---------------------------")

if ed >= 18:

    print(f"Felicidades {nombre}, eres mayor de edad y estás participando.")

else:

    print(f"Lo sentimos {nombre}, no puedes participar, no eres mayor de edad.")
```

Comment: hola tienes un parentesis de mas en nombre = (input("Ingresa tu nombre: ") deberia ser nombre = input("Ingresa tu nombre: ")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
nombre = input("Ingresa tu nombre: ")

ed = int(input("Ingresa tu edad: "))

print("---------------------------")

if ed >= 18:

    print(f"Felicidades {nombre}, eres mayor de edad y estás participando.")

else:

    print(f"Lo sentimos {nombre}, no puedes participar, no eres mayor de edad.")
```

Tenías un paréntesis de más: el primero de la primera línea. Ahora funciona correctamente.

`SyntaxError: invalid syntax` ya te indica en qué línea está el error.

Answer (score 0):

En la variable de nombre tienes un parentesis de más

```
nombre = input("Ingresa tu nombre: ")
```

Ponlo asi

Comment: @BetaM en el codigo de él tenia un parentesis de más.